# regex to replace a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I am using `sed` in linux. I have done most of the job but need help in this: 
a part of the pattern is like these:

```
document=SomeRanddomAlphaNumeric/10DigitNumber, user=
```

some examples:

I am expecting to find:

```
ducument=LKJHuasfb89/9878476578, user=
ducument=jhdn uryhf 9adu/6767898893, user=
ducument=iujjnbmr Ohndj88isju/6767898734, user=
```

and turn them to:

```
ducument=replacetext, user=
ducument=replacetext, user=
ducument=replacetext, user=
```

I am using this as sed command :

```
$ sed -i 's/regex/replacetext/g' $file.txt
```

replace text is constant but I need the regex for above command.

Comment: Are the **some examples** expected output?

Comment: no they are pattern I want to replace them. I will update the q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the preceding text does not contain any slash characters (`/`), you can match the 10 digit sequence like this:

```
sed 's|\(ducument=[^/]*/\)[0-9]\{10\}|\1replacetext|' infile
```

Comment: uh, thanks! does this command works for multiple occurances of same string in the input file?

Comment: @Youhan: if they are on the same line then yes, otherwise you need to add the `g` flag the the sed command.

Answer (score 1):

This sed should work:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\(document=\)[^,]*/\1replacetext/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work,

```
sed  's/\(ducument=\)\([^,]\+\)/\1replacetext/g'  file
```